# SQL Server nested triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Rents
(
    RentID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    StartDate SMALLDATETIME,
    EndDate SMALLDATETIME,
    Price MONEY,
    RealEstateID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    DealMadeByEmployeeID INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CHK_Rents CHECK (Price > 0 AND EndDate > StartDate),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Rents_EstatesBasicInfo 
        FOREIGN KEY (RealEstateID) REFERENCES EstatesBasicInfo(RealEstateID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Rents_Employees 
        FOREIGN KEY (DealMadeByEmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
    PurchaseID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DateBought SMALLDATETIME,
    Price MONEY CHECK (Price>0),
    RealEstateID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    DealMadeByEmployeeID INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Purchases_EstatesBasicInfo 
        FOREIGN KEY (RealEstateID) REFERENCES EstatesBasicInfo(RealEstateID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Purchases_Employees 
        FOREIGN KEY (DealMadeByEmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE EmployeesSalary
(
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CurrentSalary MONEY DEFAULT 0,-- на процент
    MonthlySalesMade INT DEFAULT 0,
    MonthlyRentsMade INT DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeesSalary_Employees 
        FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_EmployeesSalary 
        CHECK (CurrentSalary >= 0 AND MonthlySalesMade >= 0 AND MonthlyRentsMade >= 0)
);
```

Each of them has a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryPurchasesUpdate --при INSERT в Purchases таблицата
ON Purchases
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade = EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade + 1
    WHERE EmployeesSalary.EmployeeID IN (SELECT inserted.DealMadeByEmployeeID
                                         FROM inserted 
                                         WHERE DateBought IS NOT NULL)
END
                        --Update на MonthlyRentsMade
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryRentsUpdate --при INSERT в Rents таблицата
ON Rents
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET MonthlyRentsMade = MonthlyRentsMade + 1
    WHERE EmployeesSalary.EmployeeID IN (SELECT inserted.DealMadeByEmployeeID 
                                         FROM inserted
                                         WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL)
END
```

The problem comes when I want to add a trigger to `EmployeesSalary`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary
ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET CurrentSalary = CurrentSalary + ((MonthlySalesMade + MonthlyRentsMade) * 200)
    WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT i.EmployeeID 
                         FROM inserted AS i);
END
```

I want when I get an insert in the `EmployeesSalary` (by the other two triggers), the `CurrentSalary` to be updated (depending on the `EmployeeID`). The trigger cause  any errors but it doesn't work. (I think this is called nested triggers not sure...) Where is my mistake?

Comment: You seem to be using triggers to keep a running total. Why not simply calculate these values when you actually need them? You have a major logical problem here though. Your first two triggers are updating a row in EmployeesSalary but it seems like maybe that row doesn't yet exist. You might want to look at computed columns as an alternative to all these triggers. To be honest, in 20 years of database work I have written maybe a total of 3-4 triggers because there is almost always a better solution.

Comment: I do have to question the unique constraint in both your tables. As you have this a single property cannot be rented or sold more than once ever. Typically these actions happen more than once during the life of a property, especially renting.

Comment: The row exists and i can see the update but the problem is with the 3rd trigger... anyway is it possible this 3rd trigger to be fired when after some of the other triggers is fired?

Comment: well yes but my logic is if this client comes in my agency again he will be added as a new customer

Comment: Understood about the new customer part. What is the problem with the third trigger? You say it doesn't work but what does that mean? I still think a computed column would be a much better choice here instead of a trigger.

Comment: hm I'll have to check these computed columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use a computed column instead of a trigger for something like this. Here is an example. I also added ISNULL around the two columns in case you have a NULL. Otherwise the computation will always be NULL.

```
alter table EmployeesSalary
add ComputedSalary as CurrentSalary + ((isnull(MonthlySalesMade, 0) + isnull(MonthlyRentsMade, 0)) * 200) persisted
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an after-insert trigger (recursion won't occur on update table). I think where you are making a mistake is using NULL values in calculations so I would try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary
ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE es
SET CurrentSalary = coalesce(i.CurrentSalary, 0) + ((coalesce(i.MonthlySalesMade, 0) + coalesce(i.MonthlyRentsMade, 0)) * 200)
from EmployeesSalary as es
inner join inserted AS i
on i.EmployeeID = es.EmployeeID
END
```

Also, I don't like IN statements so I'm joining instead.

Comment: If they are 0, you wouldn't see any changes in the current salary. What is the result of inserting a row in the table?

Comment: still the same :D